# Sample Pearson correlation coefficient

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics, statistical-inference, probability-limit-theorems

Given paired data $\left\{(x_{1},y_{1}),\ldots ,(x_{n},y_{n})\right\}$ consisting of $n$ iid pairs ($x_i$ and $y_i$ are indenpendent), $r_{xy}$ is defined as:

$$ r_{xy}={\frac {\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-{\bar {x}})(y_{i}-{\bar {y}})}{{\sqrt {\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-{\bar {x}})^{2}}}{\sqrt {\sum _{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}-{\bar {y}})^{2}}}}}$$

where $Ex_1=\mu_1$, $Ey_1=\mu_2$, $Var [x_1]=\sigma_1^2$, $Var [y_1]=\sigma_2^2$.

What is the limiting distribution of $\frac{\sqrt{n} \, r_{xy}}{\sqrt{1-r_{xy}^2}}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Is $\sqrt{n}r_{xy}\to N(0, 1+2\frac{\mu_2^2}{\sigma_2^2}+2\frac{\mu_1^2}{\sigma_1^2})$ something you were given or something you obtained?

Comment: You removed your work, but I would actually suggest generally including your original efforts in your post. Regardless of whether your work is correct, it signals to other answerers that you have at least attempted the problem, and can also help reveal pitfalls that other questioners may encounter in similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an outline for how you can approach this.

1. *Based on your updated question, proceed directly to step 2*

First, as you seem to have noted, it suffices to find the asymptotic distribution of your expression with $\sqrt n$ in place of $\sqrt{n-2}$ since

$$\sqrt{n-2}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt n}\right)\sqrt n$$

and the first term converges in probability to 1.

2. I also suggest writing the sample correlation as

$$ r_{xy}={\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}y_{i}-(\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{i})(\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n}y_{i})}{{\sqrt {\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2} -(\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{i})^2\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n}y_{i}^{2} -(\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n}y_{i})^2\right)}}}}.$$

We'll call the population correlation coefficient $r$ (this is the same as the above expression, just replacing sample averages with expectations).

3. Now to the meat of the problem:

Define $$w_i\equiv (x_i,y_i,x_i^2,y_i^2,x_iy_i)',\\
\theta\equiv E[w_i],\Sigma\equiv \text{Var}(w_i).$$

Then if $(x_i,y_i)$ are iid and $x_i,y_i$ have finite fourth moments, CLT tells us

$$\sqrt n \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n w_i-\theta\right)\to_d N(0,\Sigma).$$

Note that you must know fourth order moments to know $\Sigma$; if you don't have explicit parameters for these, I would just leave "$\Sigma$" as is.

4. From here, I would use the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) to find the asymptotic distribution of

$$\sqrt n \left(\underbrace{g\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\right)}_{=r_{xy}/\sqrt{1-r_{xy}^2}}-\underbrace{g(\theta)}_{=r/\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right)$$

where $g:\mathbb{R}^5\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as

$$g\equiv f\circ h\\
h:\mathbb{R}^5\to\mathbb{R},\quad h(a,b,c,d,e)\equiv \frac{e-ab}{\sqrt{(c-a^2)(d-b^2)}}\\
f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\quad f(a)\equiv \frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}.$$